# Как правильно написать этот код с шаблонами?

Tags: c++, linux

При компиляции выводиться ошибка, вот такая

```
c++ main.cpp vi.cpp -o l
vi.cpp:4:3: error: ‘template<class T> class vi’ used without template parameters
 T vi::operator[](int idx)
   ^~
vi.cpp:4:25: error: ‘T operator[](int)’ must be a nonstatic member function
 T vi::operator[](int idx)
```

Вот код.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vi.h"

int main () 
{       
        vi<int> v;
        int s = v[0];
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

vi.h

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class vi {
        std::vector<T> vr;
        public:
        T operator[](int idx);
};
```

vi.cpp

```
#include "vi.h"

template<typename T>
T vi::operator[](int idx)
{
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: В дополнение к ошибке: реализация методов шаблона в `.cpp` файле ни к чему хорошему не приведет,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Шаблон - это не класс, шаблон - это не функция. Шаблон - это просто чертеж(паттерн, план), который будет использоваться компилятором для генерации семейства классов/функций.
2. Если компилятор генерирует функцию/класс из шаблона, он должен 'видеть' определения генерируемых им функций/методов класса.
3. Компилятор не собирает проект, т.е. он не видит связей между несколькими `.cpp` файлами. Это делает ваша IDE.

В вашем случае: в `main.cpp` будет создан экземпляр `vi<int>` и объявлен(не определен!) метод `vi::operator[]`. Он будет просто объявлен, т.к. в шаблоне вы однозначно указали компилятору: 'Только объяви!'(`T operator[](int idx);`). И это все не будет иметь никакого отношения к вашим определениям в `vi.cpp`.

Это все наводит на мысль, что лучше определять реализацию методов прямо в шаблоне класса, или в том же файле, где объявляется шаблон.

При крайней необходимости или огромном желании разделить интерфейс и реализацию, вы можете  воспользоваться следующим подходом:

```
// vi.h
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class vi {
        std::vector<T> vr;
        public:
        T operator[](int idx);
};
#include "vi"
// ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

```
// vi (файл без расширения)
// реализация из бывшего vi.cpp
template<typename T>
T vi<T>::operator[](int idx)
{
        return 1;
}
```

Это позволит компилятору 'видеть' одновременно и объявление шаблона, и определение шаблонных методов
Вместо файла без расширения `vi` вы можете выбрать любое другое имя с любым расширением.

Одно замечание: ваша IDE может жаловаться на подобный код, но это абсолютно легальный подход. Вы можете выполнить компиляцию и линковку из командой строки при необходимости.

---

[Templates definition and declaration. C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)

Comment: Вы вроде бы обьяснили, но переписали мой не рабочий код. Так как правильно написать то? Почему это ответом нужно считать, если правильный код не написан. Компилирую в консоли без ide. Пишу в vim.

Comment: @xverizex, в `vi.h` делаете включение файла с реализацией (`vi.cpp` в вашем случае). в примере подчеркнуто `^^^^^^`. А в `vi.cpp` включение `vi.h` делать  не надо

Comment: Я так то же делал, не работает, я подключал vi.cpp, в vi.h, в vi.cpp убирал инклуд в makefile сделал только так c++ main.cpp -o l. Всё равно не работает.

Comment: @xverizex, в файле реализации добавить аргумент шаблона `<T>` (смотрите исправленный пример)

Comment: вот так сработало, а почему так делать, не ужели нельзя отделить файлы заголовки от реализации? И если можно, то как?

Comment: @xverizex, прочтите тезисы в ответе. если этого недостаточно по ссылке есть более подробная информация. 2) отделить? один из вариантов есть в ответе, но все-таки лучше будет писать реализацию прямо в классе

Comment: @xverizex, о том, что стоит, а чего не стоит делать в С++ [можете почитать тут](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
T vi<T>::operator[](int idx)
{
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `vi<int>::operator[](int)'

Comment: Прочтите, что вам написал @AnT в комментарии к вашему вопросу...